# 800A0401 - expected end of statement on "For Output"

Tags: vbscript

I am getting the error

> 800A0401 - expected end of statement

in VBScript.

[image]

Please clarify on what is wrong.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\RAJDIQ\Desktop\Macros\11082017\SingleFile.txt", ForReading)
strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine
Set folder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\RAJDIQ\Desktop\Macros\11082017\")
Set outfile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\Users\RAJDIQ\Desktop\Macros\11082017\comparedel.txt")
myFile ="C:\Users\RAJDIQ\Desktop\Macros\11082017\Output.txt"
Open myFile for Output As #1
t = 0
Do Until outfile.AtEndOfStream
  strLine = outfile.ReadLine
  If InStr(strLine, substrToFind) <> 0 Then
    t = t+1
  Else
    [ Lines = Lines & t & ","
    Write #1, Lines]
  End If
Loop 

MsgBox "Complete"
```

Comment: `[ Lines = Lines & t & ","` is not a valid VBA statement.  What are you trying to do with that `[`?

Comment: Neither is `Write #1, Lines]`.

Comment: I am taking each record with | delimited and comparing it with other file. The record which does not have match, I am picking the line which does not have match.

Comment: But why are you using `[` and `]` characters at all? They have special meaning in VBA, and must be balanced on a single physical line.

Comment: "I am taking each record with | delimited and comparing it with other file. The record which does not have match, I am picking the line which does not have match."  Even after removing the `[` and `]`, you aren't doing that.

Comment: Were you thinking that you need to enclose a block of code within `[ ... ]`, similar to C's (I think) `{...}` syntax?  If so, you don't do that in VBA - everything between the `Then` and the `Else` is a block, and everything between the `Else` and the `End If` is a block - no special characters are needed.

Comment: I thought [] is missing is the issue. so i tried adding [] for the expected end of statement error. still the same issue

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: Without the `[` and `]`, you won't get an expected end of statement error in that code.  (You don't get it with them either, you just get "Missing end bracket" and "Invalid character" syntax errors.)  Perhaps show the actual code you were using when you got the end of statement error and we might be able to tell you why.  And, although it **shouldn't** make any difference, perhaps tell us whether this is Excel VBA, Word VBA, Outlook VBA, Access VBA, Powerpoint VBA, or some other product's VBA.

Comment: I just wrote this code in a notepad and saved it as .vbs. Please find my code below. I am trying to fetch a line from the notepad++ singleFile and check in the comparedel notepad++ to see if the record exists. If not I want that line number to be returned. The same for the set of records in singleFile. but when i run the code below, I am getting the line numbers that have matches.

Comment: Const ForReading = 1
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\\SingleFile.txt", ForReading)
strLine = objTextFile.ReadLine
Set folder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\\11082017\")
Set outfile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\\comparedel.txt")
Lines = ""
t = 0
Do Until outfile.AtEndOfStream
  strLine = outfile.ReadLine
  If InStr(strLine, substrToFind) <> 0 Then
      t=t+1
   Else
   Lines = Lines & t & ","
   
   End If
Loop 
MSGBOX Lines

Comment: Don't try to post code in comments - use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45929158/edit) link to update your question.  And stick to the current question of "why am I getting an expected end of statement error".  Once that is sorted, you can post another question to get the code working correctly.

Comment: Also explain what you mean by "and saved it as .vbs".  If this is VBA, why aren't you using the VBE.  (It's beginning to sound like this might be completely unrelated to VBA - it sounds more like VBScript.)  ARGH!!! I just tried it as VBScript and, sure enough, it gives an "Expected end of statement" error and tells you **exactly** which line and character is causing the issue.  Please, PLEASE, **PLEASE** tag you question correctly.

Comment: I will edit your question so that some VBScript programmers can look at it, and VBA programmers such as myself won't waste hours of our time trying to work out what is happening.

Comment: if adding the [] made no difference, then you should not have posted the code that includes these.   .... you are just adding a misdirection into the code when you do something like that .... always reduce the code to the smallest amount of code that still gets the error, before posting the code.

Comment: Currently you have a mixture of VBScript and VBA syntax with quite a bit of useless code and no clear indication what error occurs where exactly. Please make your code a [mcve]. Show the code as well as the exact error message *that code* produced (including error number, message, line number, etc.). [Edit] your question to do so.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Image of error message edited into the question.  An MCVE for this would be the single line saying `Open myFile for Output As #1`, with the error then occurring on line 1 character 13.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing VBA with VBScript. `Open myFile for Output As #1` isn't valid VBScript code, and neither is `Write #1` or the square brackets. In VBScript you handle files via the `FileSystemObject`.

```
Set outputFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(myFile, 2, True)
'stuff
outputFile.WriteLine "something"
'more stuff
outputFile.Close
```

The parameter `2` opens the file for writing, the parameter `True` ensures the file is created in case it's missing.

Please check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czxefwt8.aspx) for further details.